# Is it possible to get Solr's DataImportHadler to ignore fields with empty strings?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am using Solr's DataImportHandler to import data from a database. Some of the records have empty strings if there is no value for that column.

Currently the configuration I have produces Solr documents like this:

```
{
    "x": "value",
    "y": "",
    "z": 2
}
```

However I would like to ignore all fields that have no value so that documents like this are created:

```
{
    "x": "value",
    "z": 2
}
```

Is there something I can define in the configuration file for the DataImportHandler that will give me my desired results?

Comment: What's the actual value returned by the query? NULL or an empty string?

Comment: @fiskfisk The database returns an empty string.

Comment: Then you're saying that you want the empty string to be indexed, either return null (IF(...) in the SQL) or change the table definition. I'm fairly certain NULL-values won't get an entry.

Comment: @fiskfisk I have no control over the database but putting a check in the SQL I something I hadn't thought about. Ideally though I would like to find a solution that is part of the DataImportHandler configuration so that if the data source changes (e.g. importing from CSV), it will still work. Failing that though, the SQL is a good option. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the little-realized aspects of Solr is that you can plug UpdateRequestProcessor to run **after** the DIH. And, there are specialized URPs specifically for this problem.

So you could do something like this:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="skip-empty">
    <!--  Next two processors affect all fields - default configuration -->
    <processor class="TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" /> <!--  Get rid of leading/trailing spaces. Also empties all-spaces fields for next filter-->
    <processor class="RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" /> <!--  Delete fields with no content. More efficient and allows to query for presence/absence of field -->

    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Obviously, remember to also reference this chain in the DIH's handler's definition:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    ....
    <str name="update.chain">skip-empty</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You can see [the full list of the UpdateRequestProcessors](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/) at http://solr-start.com

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this in SQL as I suggested in the comment above, or if you want to have a solution in the DIH processor chain, using the [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) is a possibility. The ScriptTransformer will allow you to write a small Javascript to check if any column is an empty string, and use row.remove(fieldname) to get rid of that field completely.

If you want to write it in pure Java instead, you can also [create a reusable custom transformer for DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer).