# Unable to trim trailing spaces while indexing solr data?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a solr cloud setup with 3 zookeeper and 2 solr instance. i am trying to index data from xml file(nested document) into solr via dih and trying to remove trailing spaces so that after searching it, it should not show spaces.

file sample :

```
<doc>
   <sku>...</sku>
   <data>
     <date>..</date>
     <store>..</store>
    <econn>..</econn>
   </data>
</doc>
...
...
</product>

i have not shared the DIH , as it is working fine.

i have tried both links :- 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570545/is-it-possible-to-get-solrs-dataimporthadler-to-ignore-fields-with-empty-string

https://fossies.org/linux/solr/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/atom/conf/solrconfig.xml

actual file :-
<doc>
   <sku>abc </sku>
   <data>
      <date>2019-19-08</date>
      <store>somestore </store>
     <econn>false </econn>
   </data>
</doc>

expected output after indexing:- 
<doc>
   <sku>abc</sku>
   <data>
     <date>2019-19-08</date>
     <store>somestore</store>
     <econn>false</econn>
   </data>
</doc>

both parent and child trailing spaces should be trimmed or either of those ,which depends on context.
```

Comment: try by adding a filter to your fieldType used for the field. <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^\s+|\s+$)" replacement="" replace="all" />

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-TrimFilter

Comment: you can also handle the same in the DIH query been used and trim the data before pushing it to solr...

Comment: i am new to solr so , can you show some sample snippet for PatternReplaceFilterFactory? also i am using managed-schema and i have some 300 columns. since i dont have schema.xml , how to i make changes in managed-schema. Also you mentioned to add that in DIH query. could you elaborate?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988999/solr-managed-schema-how-to-use-it for managed schema...OR https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html

Comment: you have mentioned in your question about DIH...are your pushing the data in solr using DIH feature of solr? DIH is data import handler wherein you can configure a query to fetch the data from database to solr

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html

Comment: yes i am pushing data using  DIH . and the above link mentioned is already tried and tested. i am not sure why it is not working because there is no error. Point of importance. xml DIH with managed-schema 

Below answers are not working :- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570545/is-it-possible-to-get-solrs-dataimporthadler-to-ignore-fields-with-empty-string

https://fossies.org/linux/solr/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/atom/conf/solrconfig.xml

Comment: did you reindex the data after that?

Comment: yes, i ran the dataimport again and uploaded the configuration to zookeeper everytime i have changed something.

Comment: When you are fetching the data from database you can trim the data there itself and send the data to solr

Comment: well, its a xml file that i have received.

Comment: then I think you can try to change the fieldtype defination for the fields you are getting issue...But as you are using managed schema...you need to change to schema.xml and add the filter to <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^\s+|\s+$)" replacement="" replace="all" />

Comment: If you're going to replace the characters on the Solr side and expect the _stored value_ (i.e. the returned value) to change, you'll have to [use an update processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html). The [TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) is made for the purpose.

Comment: @MatsLindh i have already tried that. not sure why it is not working

Comment: @AbdulGaffar You'll have to add the `update.chain` parameter when submitting your new documents and give the name of the processor chain. Update Processor Chains are defined separately and not in the schema as field types.

Comment: @MatsLindh : this is what you are saying right :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570545/is-it-possible-to-get-solrs-dataimporthadler-to-ignore-fields-with-empty-string
i have tried it but its not working

Comment: Correct; then it's a good idea to find out _why_ it isn't working. Is the processor being run? (Solr will output a update processor log with `solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory`) Does using any of the other update processor commands work?

Comment: its working. i guess  TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory does not work on nested xml documents. not sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that worked for me is applying a regexTransformer inside the data-config.xml file.

```
<entity name="foo" transformer="RegexTransformer" 
<field column="new_field" xpath="path/to/field/in/xml" regex="(\s|\t)" replaceWith="" />
...
...
...
...
</entity>
```

Sometimes the answer is simple and awesome!!!!!!!