# How to ignore copying of empty or null value from DB during Reindexing(DIH) to Solr

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, mssql-jdbc

Is there any way to have a config in DIH which will ignore the null values while reindexing (DataImportHandler) from db to solr.

```
<field column="user_address " name="USR_Address" 
template="ABC_${User.user_address}"/>
```

if the value of user_address of a record is null or empty the value(null or empty) should not be copied to Solr field USR_Address during reindexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get Solr's DataImportHadler to ignore fields with empty strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570545/is-it-possible-to-get-solrs-dataimporthadler-to-ignore-fields-with-empty-string)

Comment: No,I created a custom transformer for not copying null or empty value.Thanks @Mysterion